# How to control the visible area (up and down the line) in NumberLinePlot?

Tags: visualization, number-representation

How can you control the up and down line visible part of the graph?

The target if view arrosw and text below the line (purple arrow) and if it´s posible make great the upper area

```
muestra = {600, 800, 950}
muestraMean = Mean[muestra]
muestraMedian = Median[muestra]
NumberLinePlot[
  {600, 800, 950}, 
  Spacings -> {0.08}, 
  PlotStyle -> Directive[PointSize[0.016]], 
  LabelStyle -> {16, Bold}, 
  ImageSize -> Full, PlotTheme -> {{}},
  Epilog -> {
    Red, Thickness[0.006], 
    Arrow[{{muestraMean, 0.84}, {muestraMean, 0.24}}],
    Text[Style["Mean", 20, Bold], {muestraMean, 1.2}],
    Lighter[Blue], Thickness[0.006], 
    Arrow[{{muestraMedian, -0.64}, {muestraMedian, -0.12}}],
    Text[Style["Median", 24, Bold], {muestraMean, -0.74}]}
]
```

Edit after kglr comment. Solved!
    ImagePadding -> {{0, 0}, {100, 20}}

Edit after Mathematica change the ratio of the image:
How to control the dimensions of the resultant image?.  ImageSize don´t solve this question, the orange frame is very biggher than the image, as you can see 
[image]

Comment: try `ImagePadding -> {{10, 10}, {50, 100}}` . Play with the numbers to get the desired result.

Comment: @kglr an to control the dimensions of the image?, not Small, Large,...  width and heigth

Comment: ImageSize takes numerical arguments as well. Look it up in the docs, it’s amazing what you can find in there.

Comment: @MarcoB not in this case, I tried it before question